# is it okay to use spaces for value attribute in option tag? will the spaces cause an error when posting the data to the database?

Tags: html, forms, dropdown, html-select

```
 <form>
<label for="dropdown">Which option best describes your current role? </label> 
  <select name="current role" id="dropdown">
          <option value="Prefer not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

1.This is a dropdown list with 1 option.
2.In the option tag value attribute I have used space to define the value.
3.I normally try using underscores.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure whether it will cause an error(I think it will), but if I were you, I would stick to using underscores or dashes, or simply writing in camel case.